# Classic ASP Cookie Vulnerability

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

I have a simple login page on a classic asp page.

It takes the username field from a form ("un") and the password ("pw") and does the following with them:

```
<%
    un = newstr(request.form("un"))
    pw = newstr(request.form("pw"))

    SQL = "SELECT * from my_table WHERE un = '"&un&"' AND pw = '"&pw&"'"
    set cRS = oConn.Execute(SQL)

    if cRS.EOF then
    %>

        <p>Unable to log you in. Please <a href="default.asp">try logging in again</a>.</p>

    <%
    elseif NOT cRS.EOF then

        Response.Cookies("test") = "jeQmV4'QG)Eu'N-XSTC;pZeuwqUsjBdVv>Sqr!]ZhzB{dJ'p-#cYSdwY"
        Response.Cookies("test").Expires = Date() + 365

        response.redirect "main.asp"

    end if

end if
%>
```

Then I have some simple validation at the top of each page whose contain I only want logged in users to be able to see, which does this:

```
<%
test = Request.Cookies("test")
if test = "" OR test <> "jeQmV4'QG)Eu'N-XSTC;pZeuwqUsjBdVv>Sqr!]ZhzB{dJ'p-#cYSdwY" then response.redirect("default.asp")
%>
```

I wanted to check - is that naively simple?

Could someone easily hack into my site, by e.g. setting a cookie on their computer, called "test" and whose value = "jeQmV4'QG)Eu'N-XSTC;pZeuwqUsjBdVv>Sqr!]ZhzB{dJ'p-#cYSdwY"?

Or wouldn't it be pretty unlikely someone would guess that string value of "jeQmV4'QG)Eu'N-XSTC;pZeuwqUsjBdVv>Sqr!]ZhzB{dJ'p-#cYSdwY"?

Thanks

Comment: That's more than a cookie vulnerability

Comment: You are reusing the same string. The correct way to do what you are trying to achieve is either us ASP sessions (they will be different for each user) or make your own Key different for each user, and then store that in your database.  It will still be a cookie vulnerability and lead to session hijacking if someone guesses the key, but since they are different for each user then guessing is not likely.  You could take it a second step (what most banks do) by detecting the device (usually ip address) and making sure those elements also match before granting access.

Answer (score 4):

First off, someone could break your system by trying to pass in user names like

> ';DROP TABLE Users

http://xkcd.com/327/

Always, always use parameterized queries.

Never trust the UI for anything related to security.  The client can observe all cookies that you set, and return any cookie back to you that it wants to.  If this is not HTTPS, someone in the middle could also observe the cookie being sent back and forth.

Don't re-invent security frameworks.  They are very hard to get right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That "newstr" is a simple function which takes the input and paramterises the input. So basically cookies are a waste of time for security? I don't have the option of using a secure server on my site unfortunately. Is the next best alternative to use session variables instead? I've used them in the past but there is a 15 minute timeout set by my host for them which means users have to keep logging in, and also risk losing data if they have e.g. typed lots in, session times out, they submit a form, and they are redirected to the login page... Thanks again

Comment: You probably mean that `newstr` attempts to sanitize the input to thwart SQL injection attacks.  Sanitizing is not enough, see e.g. http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-injection-prevention/  Simply setting a "magic value" in a cookie is not safe/secure.  Whether it is *safe enough* for your purposes depends on what you are trying to protect, and how bad it would be if a determined hacker got in.  There are *many* low-cost hosting providers.  If yours will not extend the session timeout, shop around.

Comment: The database is the security.  The cookie or session value is only for convenience so the user doesn't have to keep logging in.  You could just set the cookie equal to "True" or "False", but give the cookie a specific name which is domain related.  The security aspect for cookies comes into play if the machine is private or public.  Hence most users are asked if they want to be "remembered" on this machine before setting a value.  Another technique is to set a flag in the database that the user is logged in.  That value can be cleared based on a time value also.

Comment: Also want to set HTTP only cookies.